# PHP-SQL Automatically add data with increment

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I want to create a php-sql application for my case study where in I have these attributes:

> > Book ID,
> >     Book Name,
> >     Author,
> >     Editor,
> >     ISBN

the user will input the Book Name, Book ID, Author and Editor
and automatically there will be an input for ISBN Number that is increments every time the user will input.
Is that possible anyway? Well thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I don't think that the ISBN property can be automatically input.

Comment: Yes it's possible. What part are you having problems with? Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Cause I want it to be like 8009-9000 and so the ending number will increment.

Comment: You can have a field named ISBN and have it auto-increment, but it wouldn't be a true ISBN as in International Standard Book Number. You already have a Book ID field for internal purposes (presumably), so the true ISBNs you would have to get from some third party source.

Comment: don't worry about the ISBN for each book. I just need this to be auto increment like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear why you need this but you can achieve your goal with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger and a separate table for sequencing

Tables

```sql
-- A sequencing table
CREATE TABLE book_seq 
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
-- Set initial value
ALTER TABLE book_seq AUTO_INCREMENT = 9000;

CREATE TABLE books
(
  book_id   INT,
  book_name VARCHAR(256), 
  author    VARCHAR(256),
  editor    VARCHAR(256),
  isbn      VARCHAR(12)
);
```

A trigger

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_book_seq
BEFORE INSERT ON books
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO book_seq VALUES(NULL);
  SET NEW.isbn = CONCAT('8000-', LAST_INSERT_ID());
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now you can simply insert rows

```sql
INSERT INTO books (book_id, book_name, author, editor) VALUES
(1, 'Book1 Title', 'Author1', 'Editor1'),
(2, 'Book2 Title', 'Author2', 'Editor1');
```

Your pseudo ISBN number will be auto-generated

```
| BOOK_ID |   BOOK_NAME |  AUTHOR |  EDITOR |      ISBN |
---------------------------------------------------------
|       1 | Book1 Title | Author1 | Editor1 | 8000-9000 |
|       2 | Book2 Title | Author2 | Editor1 | 8000-9001 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c5d6/1)** demo

---

Another, much simpler, approach is to use `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax and calculate next pseudo ISBN number at the time of insert with the query like this

```sql
INSERT INTO books (book_id, book_name, author, editor, isbn) 
SELECT 1, 'Book1 Title', 'Author1', 'Editor1',
       CONCAT('8000-', COALESCE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(MAX(isbn), '-', -1), '8999') + 1) new_value
  FROM books
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/363b5)** demo

**Note:** the major drawback of this approach is that it might fail under heavy load in concurrent environment when two or more concurrent users may have get the same `MAX(isbn)` value thus producing rows with the duplicate isbn number.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can make `ISBN` field as auto-increment, starting with a definite number

Comment: @user2497414 you won't need any Book Id if you're using ISBN, as ISBN is already unique. And I'm not sure why you want to use auto-increment for ISBN, as for any book its fixed, and you can't just add up on the ISBN number, please clarify...

Answer (score 0):

Like Trung-Hieu Le wrote in his comment:
The ISBN shouldn't be an automatic input but if you REALLY want that you should have a look at
[Auto Increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on your won ISBN numbers for a specific project then yes you can set a field to auto increment starting for your desirable number,

but if it is not only your won ISBN numbers and you need real books ISBN number then you will need to have an ISBN number database that contain books ISBN numbers then whenever a user input a book a name and other details then the ISBN will be automatically inserted in your ISBN field based on a match query with the book information...

hope this help

Comment: yeah i just need ISBN of books for a specific project. the ingenuity of the isbn number isn't important at all. But how to do a field with auto increment of a set number like 8009-9000 <--- the last number will increment.